# IIS 7 web.config redirect all traffic except that of a specific directory

Tags: redirect, dns, web-config

I am using the web.config file to redirect all of my traffic from one domain to another.  It works perfectly, but because I have a mobile app on the market with older versions pointing to the original domain, I need to leave a single directly intact.

For example:
All traffic from www.domain1.com will redirect to www.domain2.com
with the exception of all traffic going to www.domain1.com/folder1/